Plotting a Semi-Log Plot using Specific Time Intervals
I am fairly new to Matlab plotting and I can't figure out the semi-log plotting.
I would like to plot the following as a semi-log plot:
Y-axis

V = 50 for t < 0.05

V = 31.38 + 0.931/t for 0.05 ≤ t ≥ 7.758

V = 31.5 for t ≥ 7.758

The Y-axis will have intervals of 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60.


X-axis

The X-axis (semi-log) would range from [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100).

I would also like to add a marker for 7 on the x-axis.


Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
